# 97 f 150 headlight problem

Tags: ford, headlight, f-150

97 Ford f 150 Headlights High beams are low beams and low beams are high beams neither are very bright. Checked bulb in truck and it's a 9004 looked up what it calls for and it says 9007. Would this be the cause of the problem.